# Kubernetes : PVC binding status in pending

Tags: kubernetes

I create a PV and claimed the PV through PVC. I see that PV is created but the PVC binding status is stuck in pending.When i looked at the describe pvc output , I see that no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set. From the documentation I understand that storage class isnt mandatory . So, am unsure on what's missing in the PVC file.

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolume

metadata:
  name: pv-ghost
  labels:
    pv: pv-ghost

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi

  hostPath:
    path: /ghost/data
--------------------------
apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:
  name: pvc-ghost

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany

  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv: pv-ghost
```

Out of describe PV and PVC

```
    kubectl describe pv pv-ghost
    Name:            pv-ghost
    Labels:          pv=pv-ghost
    Annotations:     <none>
    Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
    StorageClass:
    Status:          Available
    Claim:
    Reclaim Policy:  Retain
    Access Modes:    RWX
    Capacity:        3Gi
    Node Affinity:   <none>
    Message:
    Source:
        Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
        Path:          /ghost/data
        HostPathType:
    Events:            <none>
kubectl describe pvc pvc-ghost
Name:          pvc-ghost
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type       Reason         Age                  From                         Message
  ----       ------         ----                 ----                         -------
  Normal     FailedBinding  8m44s (x8 over 10m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
  Normal     FailedBinding  61s (x5 over 2m3s)   persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
Mounted By:  <none>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the volume source manually.

ReadWriteMany is only available for `AzureFile`, `CephFS`, `Glusterfs`, `Quobyte`, `NFS`, `PortworxVolume`.
Also `Flexvolume` depending on the drivers and `VsphereVolume` works when pods are collocated.
You can read it all in Kubernetes docs regarding [Volume Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

An example PV for aws would look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi # Doesn't really matter, as EFS does not enforce it anyway
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
    - rsize=1048576
    - wsize=1048576
    - timeo=300
    - retrans=2
  nfs:
    path: /
    server: fs-XXX.efs.eu-central-2.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above issue,

1. The `Capacity` specified in the persistent volume is lesser than the Persistent volume claim **Capacity**. Try either increasing the `Capacity` number in the Persistent volume to **5Gi** or reducing the `Capacity` number in the Persistent volume claim to **3Gi**.
2. When you are using a **hostPath** in the **Persistent volume** the `accessModes` should be `ReadWriteOnce`.

Comment: I changed the accessmode to RWO and changed the capacity on PV to 5Gi and PVC to 3Gi. The status still shows pending

Comment: when i look at the event I see the following
```  Type       Reason         Age                   From                         Message
  ----       ------         ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal     FailedBinding  4m22s (x5 over 5m8s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Comment: @IT_novice Can you run the `journalctl -ef` on the host where the persistent volume claim is trying to bound the persistent volume and send it. Are you the /ghost/data has the right permissions to be writable?

Comment: Dec 03 20:58:12 kube-node-0 kernel: xt_physdev: using --physdev-out and --physdev-is-out are only supported in the FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains with bridged traffic.
Dec 03 20:58:21 kube-node-0 kubelet[393]: E1203 20:58:21.280304     393 azure_dd.go:147] failed to get azure cloud in GetVolumeLimits, plugin.host: kube-node-0

Comment: ..i checked on the permission and the folder indeed has write permissions

Comment: If it is running on a RHEL/CentOS can you try the following, Edit file `/etc/sysconfig/kubelet` on your master server (control plane), and add the following:

`KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--feature-gates=AttachVolumeLimit=false`

If you already have extra arguments in there, just add this one at the end of the line. Then restart kubelet on your master server:

`sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: It's running on raspbian and I did try changing the kubelet args earlier (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69503) but it didnt work. The status still showing pending

Comment: I just read that a hostPath PersistentVolume must be used only in a single-node cluster. Kubernetes does not support hostPath on a multi-node cluster currently. I'm running a two node cluster ( 1 Master - 2 worker nodes) on raspberry pi. May be this is causing the issue

Comment: That seems legitimate, hostPath in multi-node is not currently supported by Kubernetes. I bet, if they does it would not be an appropriate method for production use. Good catch @IT_novice !

Answer (score 0):

Hostpath method is currently not supported in a multi-node cluster.